# How to perform compile-time checks for Android version within a Java library in an Android project?

Tags: java, android, sdk, version, android-version

I have a Java library that is created within an Android project, and I need to perform compile-time checks based on the Android version. The library is intended to handle certain functionalities differently depending on the Android version it's being compiled against.

The reason for needing to check the Android version at compile time is to handle API differences and ensure compatibility across different Android versions. For instance, I want to include specific code blocks or handle certain behaviors differently based on whether the Android version is below or above a certain threshold.

I have attempted to use **Build.VERSION.SDK_INT** within the Java library, but this approach only provides runtime checks. I need a solution that allows me to perform checks during the compilation phase itself.

I've researched using Gradle's **android.compileSdkVersion** and android.defaultConfig.minSdkVersion properties, but I'm not sure how to integrate them into the Java library's codebase for compile-time checks.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve compile-time checks for Android version within a Java library would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Specific Questions:**

What is the recommended approach for checking the Android version at compile time within a Java library that's part of an Android project?
Are there any Gradle plugins or tools that can help with conditional compilation based on the Android version?
How can I conditionally include or exclude code blocks in my Java library based on the Android version during compilation?

Answer (score 0):

hint : if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)